# Undirected combinations of actors in the same movie

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

I'm not exactly sure how to describe the operation that I'm trying to do. I have a data frame with two columns (movies and actors). I want to create from this a list of unique 2-actor combinations based on movies they are in together. Below is code that creates an example of the data frame that I have, and another data frame which is the results that I want.

```r
start_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~movie, ~actor,
  "titanic", "john",
  "star wars", "john",
  "baby driver", "john",
  "shawshank", "billy",
  "titanic", "billy",
  "star wars", "sarah",
  "titanic", "sarah"
)

end_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~movie, ~actor1, ~actor2,
  "titanic", "john", "billy",
  "titanic", "john", "sarah",
  "titanic", "billy", "sarah",
  "star wars", "john", "sarah"
)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks! Bonus points if it is short++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combn(..., 2)` to find two combination of actors, which can be converted to a two column *tibble* and stored in a list column with `summarize`; To get a flat data frame, use `unnest`:

```
library(tidyverse)

start_data %>% 
    group_by(movie) %>% 
    summarise(acts = list(
        if(length(actor) > 1) set_names(as.tibble(t(combn(actor, 2))), c('actor1', 'actor2')) 
        else tibble()
    )) %>% 
    unnest()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      movie actor1 actor2
#      <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1 star wars   john  sarah
#2   titanic   john  billy
#3   titanic   john  sarah
#4   titanic  billy  sarah
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The only addition I made was adding `filter(actor1 != actor2)` to remove a few cases. This is likely a problem with my data though.

Comment: It's likely you have duplicated actors in each movie; You can either apply a filter after as you did, or remove duplicates from beginning as `combn(unique(actor), 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

inner_join(start_data, start_data, by = "movie") %>% 
  filter(actor.x != actor.y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(combo = str_c(min(actor.x, actor.y), "_", max(actor.x, actor.y))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(movie, combo) %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  separate(combo, c("actor1", "actor2"))
```

Comment: This seems to work as well as the other poster. My mistake was not providing proper sample actor data. The format should be `Lastname Firstname`. It would take some minor hacking to get your method to work. Another problem with your method is that you failed to mention str_c comes from the stringr package. Not hard to find though. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Just change `str_c` to `paste0` if you don't want to use stringr